# When the VLCMediaPlayer is set to play a different remote media, how to clear the last displayed frame

Tags: vlckit

I have an iOS app that plays a few remote media.  When the user switches to a different video, I set the VLCMediaPlayer.media to a new remote media.  The problem I have is the last video still has a frame in the video player paused. How do I clear that frame and show a black screen

Comment: you will have to do this manually by removing the view or putting something on top. This is a libvlc limitation